# How can I find rows in a pandas dataframe where value of col1 for row_x == value of col2 for row_y?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns. 2 of those columns should be equal but in separate rows, and the third column should be equal in both rows.

For example, given dataframe df[A, B, C], find row_x and row_y such that:

`(df.iloc[x, A] == df.iloc[y, B]) and (df.iloc[x, B] == df.iloc[y, A]) and (df.iloc[x, C] == df.iloc[y, C])`

Is there a better way than iterating through the frame to get the rows with swapped columns?

```
A = [30,31]+list(range(2,8,1))+[38,39]
B = range(10,0,-1)
C = [True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})

Out[]: df
    A   B   C
0   30  10  True
1   31  9   False
2   2   8   True
3   3   7   False
4   4   6   False
5   5   5   False
6   6   4   True
7   7   3   False
8   38  2   True
9   39  1   False


Required output:
    A   B   C
3   3   7   False
5   5   5   False
7   7   3   False
```

Only row 3, 5, and 7 satisfy the above conditions. I will further remove row 5 since I am not interested in rows with column A = column B. Note that row 4 and row 6 also had swapped values in column A and B, but a different value in column C.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 
to group based on column `C`.Use [GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) 
to check the common values ​​of both series (`A` and `B`), 
then  you can use [DataFrame.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to perform a [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
new_df=df[df.groupby('C').apply(lambda x: x['A'].isin(x['B'])&x['B'].isin(x['A'])).unstack().any()]
print(new_df)


   A  B      C
3  3  7  False
5  5  5  False
7  7  3  False
```

---

**In response to your comment:**

```
df['A'].isin(df['B'])

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

---

```
df['A']==df['B']        

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: It is only way for contact you ;)

Comment: @ansev It works! Thanks!
Could you clarify why (x['A'].isin(x['B']) & x['B'].isin(x['A'])) works here? I initially thought the answer should be `( lambda x: (x['A'] == x['B'] & x['B'] == x['A']) )`.

Comment: `isin` is used to compare if a value that is in A is also in B, regardless of the index

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can see the difference between `==` and `isin`

Comment: Please tell me if I have clarified your doubt. I would appreciate it if you could accept and / or vote my answer

Answer (score 1):

The key is to merge the dataframe to itself, matching `B` column to `A` column:

```
df = df.merge(df.rename({'B': 'A', 'A': 'AfromB', 'C': 'CfromB'}, axis=1), how='left')
df = df[(df['B'] == df['AfromB']) & (df['C'] == df['CfromB'])].drop(['AfromB', 'CfromB'], axis=1)
```